# Dificuldade para implementar JavaMail!

Tags: spring-boot, javamail

Minha aplicação está se comportando de uma forma muito estanha, ao executar a aplicação Spring Boot ele gera os logs informando que enviou o email usando Scheduled, porém ao consulta minha conta de email percebo que não gerou nenhum email.

As mensagens de Logs são esses;

```
Hibernate: select lancamento0_.codigo as codigo1_1_, lancamento0_.codigo_categoria as codigo_c8_1_, lancamento0_.data_pagamento as data_pag2_1_, lancamento0_.data_vencimento as data_ven3_1_, lancamento0_.descricao as descrica4_1_, lancamento0_.observacao as observac5_1_, lancamento0_.codigo_pessoa as codigo_p9_1_, lancamento0_.tipo as tipo6_1_, lancamento0_.valor as valor7_1_ from lancamento lancamento0_ where lancamento0_.data_vencimento<=? and (lancamento0_.data_pagamento is null)
Hibernate: select categoria0_.codigo as codigo1_0_0_, categoria0_.nome as nome2_0_0_ from categoria categoria0_ where categoria0_.codigo=?
Hibernate: select pessoa0_.codigo as codigo1_3_0_, pessoa0_.ativo as ativo2_3_0_, pessoa0_.bairro as bairro3_3_0_, pessoa0_.cep as cep4_3_0_, pessoa0_.cidade as cidade5_3_0_, pessoa0_.complemento as compleme6_3_0_, pessoa0_.estado as estado7_3_0_, pessoa0_.logradouro as logradou8_3_0_, pessoa0_.numero as numero9_3_0_, pessoa0_.nome as nome10_3_0_ from pessoa pessoa0_ where pessoa0_.codigo=?
Hibernate: select categoria0_.codigo as codigo1_0_0_, categoria0_.nome as nome2_0_0_ from categoria categoria0_ where categoria0_.codigo=?
Hibernate: select pessoa0_.codigo as codigo1_3_0_, pessoa0_.ativo as ativo2_3_0_, pessoa0_.bairro as bairro3_3_0_, pessoa0_.cep as cep4_3_0_, pessoa0_.cidade as cidade5_3_0_, pessoa0_.complemento as compleme6_3_0_, pessoa0_.estado as estado7_3_0_, pessoa0_.logradouro as logradou8_3_0_, pessoa0_.numero as numero9_3_0_, pessoa0_.nome as nome10_3_0_ from pessoa pessoa0_ where pessoa0_.codigo=?
Hibernate: select pessoa0_.codigo as codigo1_3_0_, pessoa0_.ativo as ativo2_3_0_, pessoa0_.bairro as bairro3_3_0_, pessoa0_.cep as cep4_3_0_, pessoa0_.cidade as cidade5_3_0_, pessoa0_.complemento as compleme6_3_0_, pessoa0_.estado as estado7_3_0_, pessoa0_.logradouro as logradou8_3_0_, pessoa0_.numero as numero9_3_0_, pessoa0_.nome as nome10_3_0_ from pessoa pessoa0_ where pessoa0_.codigo=?
Hibernate: select pessoa0_.codigo as codigo1_3_0_, pessoa0_.ativo as ativo2_3_0_, pessoa0_.bairro as bairro3_3_0_, pessoa0_.cep as cep4_3_0_, pessoa0_.cidade as cidade5_3_0_, pessoa0_.complemento as compleme6_3_0_, pessoa0_.estado as estado7_3_0_, pessoa0_.logradouro as logradou8_3_0_, pessoa0_.numero as numero9_3_0_, pessoa0_.nome as nome10_3_0_ from pessoa pessoa0_ where pessoa0_.codigo=?
Hibernate: select pessoa0_.codigo as codigo1_3_0_, pessoa0_.ativo as ativo2_3_0_, pessoa0_.bairro as bairro3_3_0_, pessoa0_.cep as cep4_3_0_, pessoa0_.cidade as cidade5_3_0_, pessoa0_.complemento as compleme6_3_0_, pessoa0_.estado as estado7_3_0_, pessoa0_.logradouro as logradou8_3_0_, pessoa0_.numero as numero9_3_0_, pessoa0_.nome as nome10_3_0_ from pessoa pessoa0_ where pessoa0_.codigo=?
Hibernate: select categoria0_.codigo as codigo1_0_0_, categoria0_.nome as nome2_0_0_ from categoria categoria0_ where categoria0_.codigo=?
2018-09-28 12:35:24.779  INFO 6160 --- [pool-2-thread-1] c.p.kwan.service.LancamentoService       : Exitem 8 lançamentos vencidos.
Hibernate: select usuario0_.codigo as codigo1_4_, usuario0_.email as email2_4_, usuario0_.nome as nome3_4_, usuario0_.senha as senha4_4_ from usuario usuario0_ left outer join usuario_permissao permissoes1_ on usuario0_.codigo=permissoes1_.codigo_usuario left outer join permissao permissao2_ on permissoes1_.codigo_permissao=permissao2_.codigo where permissao2_.descricao=?
Hibernate: select permissoes0_.codigo_usuario as codigo_u1_5_0_, permissoes0_.codigo_permissao as codigo_p2_5_0_, permissao1_.codigo as codigo1_2_1_, permissao1_.descricao as descrica2_2_1_ from usuario_permissao permissoes0_ inner join permissao permissao1_ on permissoes0_.codigo_permissao=permissao1_.codigo where permissoes0_.codigo_usuario=?
Hibernate: select permissoes0_.codigo_usuario as codigo_u1_5_0_, permissoes0_.codigo_permissao as codigo_p2_5_0_, permissao1_.codigo as codigo1_2_1_, permissao1_.descricao as descrica2_2_1_ from usuario_permissao permissoes0_ inner join permissao permissao1_ on permissoes0_.codigo_permissao=permissao1_.codigo where permissoes0_.codigo_usuario=?
2018-09-28 12:35:30.955  INFO 6160 --- [pool-2-thread-1] c.p.kwan.service.LancamentoService       : Envio de e-mail de aviso concluído.
```

Não sei o que tem de errado, configurei corretamente o protocolo de email.

```
@Configuration
```

public class MailConfig {

```
@Autowired
private KwanApiProperty property;

@Bean
public JavaMailSender javaMailSender() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);
    props.put("mail.smtp.connectiontimeout", 10000);

    JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    mailSender.setJavaMailProperties(props);
    mailSender.setHost(property.getMail().getHost());
    mailSender.setPort(property.getMail().getPort());
    mailSender.setUsername(property.getMail().getUsername());
    mailSender.setPassword(property.getMail().getPassword());

    return mailSender;
}
```

}

O arquivo que faz tudo é esse;

```
package com.projeto.kwan.mail;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationReadyEvent;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.context.Context;

import com.projeto.kwan.model.Lancamento;
import com.projeto.kwan.model.Usuario;
import com.projeto.kwan.repository.LancamentoRepository;

@Component
public class Mailer {

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

    @Autowired
    private TemplateEngine thymeleaf;




//  @Autowired
//  private LancamentoRepository repo;
//  @EventListener
//  private void teste(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
//      String template = "mail/aviso-lancamentos-vencidos";
//      
//      List<Lancamento> lista = repo.findAll();
//      
//      Map<String, Object> variaveis = new HashMap<>();
//      variaveis.put("lancamentos", lista);
//      
//      this.enviarEmail("testewladimir7@gmail.com", 
//              Arrays.asList("tecnico100@gmail.com"), 
//              "Testando", template, variaveis);
//      System.out.println("Terminado o envio de e-mail...");
//  }


    public void avisarSobreLancamentosVencidos(
            List<Lancamento> vencidos, List<Usuario> destinatarios) {
        Map<String, Object> variaveis = new HashMap<>();
        variaveis.put("lancamentos", vencidos);

        List<String> emails = destinatarios.stream()
                .map(u -> u.getEmail())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        this.enviarEmail("testewladimir7@gmail.com", 
                emails, 
                "Lançamentos vencidos", 
                "mail/aviso-lancamentos-vencidos", 
                variaveis);
    }

    public void enviarEmail(String remetente, 
            List<String> destinatarios, String assunto, String template, 
            Map<String, Object> variaveis) {
        Context context = new Context(new Locale("pt", "BR"));

        variaveis.entrySet().forEach(
                e -> context.setVariable(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));

        String mensagem = thymeleaf.process(template, context);

        this.enviarEmail(remetente, destinatarios, assunto, mensagem);
    }

    public void enviarEmail(String remetente, 
            List<String> destinatarios, String assunto, String mensagem) {
        try {
            MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();

            MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, "UTF-8");
            helper.setFrom(remetente);
            helper.setTo(destinatarios.toArray(new String[destinatarios.size()]));
            helper.setSubject(assunto);
            helper.setText(mensagem, true);

            mailSender.send(mimeMessage);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Problemas com o envio de e-mail!", e); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que você precisa rodar seu código em modo debug colocando um point break para analisar esta implementação de envio de e-mail. Pelo log que você colou me parece que ele nem é chamado, ou se é chamado está enviando normalmente.

O debug resolveria essa sua dúvida.

Comment: A classe Mailer  é o que faz tudo, onde eu poderia colocar o break point? você tem toda razão em relação ao debug, mas não sei onde colocar?

Comment: poderia dar uma olhada na minha postagem? Eu acabei de atualizar

Comment: Agora eu fiquei confuso, pois não consegui entender qual dos dois métodos de envio de e-mail você está usando.

Você pode ir direto no método que está usando para envio de e-mail, qual de fato realiza o procedimento do envio e adicione o break point na primeira linha após a declaração do método.

Daí verifique se consegue utilizar as informações coletadas para ter uma ideia se todas as funções estão ocorrendo corretamente.

Comment: acabei de fazer o debug, ele estava enviando o email para admin@kwan.com , porém esse email não existe, é porque a minha aplicação tem autenticação de usuário sendo autenticado de uma conta de email fictício, para corrigir coloquei emails reais, funcionou, muito obrigado novato, ficou bem na fita hein, brincaderia kkkkk, muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Hahahaha ;) valeu cara!